# Can Any of You Draw the Interleaved 2 of 5 Barcode Type for the Following Number?

Tags: barcode

I'd doing some tests with the barcode generator I made and when I input some bill barcode numbers for simulating, it draws fine but just in the beginning of the barcode. the sequence of black and white stripes just match with the ones shown in the beginning of the printed bill. in some bills it keeps matching till some pairs of numbers ahead, then it looses matching. that's why I'd like some of you to draw a barcode of interleaved 2 of 5 type regarding the following binary number, so I can compare with mine: 10100100011001000110110001001000000110111100000011. this sequence is the decimal number 3419157411. or separated by pairs.

```
34 = 1010010001
19 = 1001000110
15 = 1100010010
74 = 0000011011
11 = 1100000011
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [so] is not some sort of art class

Comment: Use an on-line bar code generator. I'm sure Google will find a few.

Comment: art class? you might be kidding! 11,000 dollars are waiting for me! they say: finish this and I'll be yours. so if any you can help me, I'll appreciate it! I'll try google again while a good soul come up and help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I think Thor My is trying to make his own barcode generator, which is definitely a programming feat. Good luck, Thor.For future reference, I guess you don't want to use the term "draw", maybe "produce" or "generate" because drawing a barcode implies a manual act in most English language contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I got "101011101110100010100011101000101000111011100010100010111010101000111011100011100010101011100011101"

You can use my Int 2of5 [generator](http://brian-p-anderson.github.io/JS-Barcodes/). Set the width to at least 8 and make sure to select Interleaved 2 of 5 from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your barcode against an existing barcode generator, try bwip-js at http://metafloor.github.io/bwip-js.  It has on online generator that supports several variations of 2 of 5 code, including interleaved.  (Disclosure: I am the author of bwip-js.)